# Appropriate c# driver for Mongo 2.2.4

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I just upgraded my Mongo on local machine to 2.2.4 and I am using it with my .Net environment. Now it was my turn to find out which Mongo-C# driver works best for Mongo 2.2.4 and I did searched a lot of forums including 10gen site but there is no official statement from 10gen saying which version of Mongo c# driver would work best for 2.2.4.

This is little confusing for me. Although the current Mongo-c# driver works fine but is it the best driver to work with Mongo? There is no answer to that.

Any suggestions? My current Mongo-c# driver is 1.6.1.4678.

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MongoDB Wire Protocol](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) has not changed for some time and MongoDB's design allows [every MongoDB driver to support every command](http://emptysquare.net/blog/yes-every-mongodb-driver-supports-every-command/).  The 1.6 C#/.NET driver will continue to work for the foreseeable future, but you may be missing out on ongoing driver improvements such as bug fixes, command helpers, and support for newer MongoDB server features.  The C#/.NET driver currently has very active testing & development.

The [1.7 C#/.NET driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-announce/l7CZq06WOU0) deprecates SafeMode and replaces it with WriteConcern.  There is also a new [MongoClient class](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient) which was introduced across the MongoDB drivers in November, 2012.  These changes are unlikely to affect your current application, but newer tutorials and documentation will make reference to the current defaults and behaviour.

As far as the "best" driver, that will depend on whether you actually need any to take advantage of helpers for newer features and defaults. Given your current 1.6.1 driver is just over six months old I would suggest testing an upgrade to the latest version.  There have been significant improvements and it can be easier to upgrade incrementally rather than trying to figure out the diffs between many major versions.

If you are going to upgrade now, I would chose the latest driver available that has been out for a few weeks (currently the [1.8.1 release on April 9th](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-announce/JcnbON21FTE)).

You can browse a list of the changes between releases by searching the [CSHARP project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP) in the public MongoDB Jira issue tracker.  There is a [Versions tab](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel) which allows you to see issues for specific versions, or you can do a custom search for a list of fixVersions.

Comment: This might be out of context but wanted to ask you since we are already on it. What is difference between "Safe mode" and "Write Concern"?

Comment: @Californicated: Essentially "Safe mode" is the older (and deprecated) name for WriteConcern. Safe mode has evolved from simpler "should this write be acknowledged" semantics to include additional [write concerns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) such as tagged writes for replica sets. In C#/.NET drivers prior to 1.7 the default was for SafeMode to be "off" (Unacknowledged); 1.7 introduced MongoClient where Acknowledged is the default write concern. The new WriteConcern class more appropriately reflects the intended usage and is consistent with other supported driver APIs.